# SQL Query or Linq query to get No of Events per day from database

Tags: sql, linq

SQL query or linq query to get the number of events per day for each and every record (Id), Event Jupiter, Earth and Mars comes under 7th Date so number of events is 3(considering time).

```
1. A event can start and end in the same day.
2. A event can start today and end after 3 days.

 Table Name:  **Events**

    **Id**  **Name**  **StartDateWithTime**        **EndDateWithTime**

    1        Sun       2017-11-28 00:00:00.000     2017-11-29 0:00:00.000
    2        Moon      2017-11-28 00:00:00.000     2017-12-01 10:00:00.000
    3        Earth     2017-11-07 00:00:00.000     2017-11-30 00:40:00.000
    4        Jupiter   2017-11-07 00:00:00.000     2017-11-07 20:00:00.000
    5        Mars      2017-11-07 10:00:00.000     2017-12-07 20:10:00.000
```

SQL query or linq query to get the number of events per day

Comment: Could you clarify what you want the results to look like? So record 1 covers two days so you would have Id 1, 2017-11-28 and a count, then Id 1, 2017-11 and a count?

Comment: is that worked for you ??????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have to take the `COUNT` of number of events occurring each day which means `GROUPing BY` on the dates themselves. You can try this :

```
 SELECT         COUNT(*) AS NumberOfEvents,
                CONVERT(DATE, event.StartDateWithTime) as StartDateWithTime
 FROM           Events event
 GROUP BY       CONVERT(DATE,event.StartDateWithTime)
 ORDER BY       CONVERT(DATE,event.StartDateWithTime)
```

You can see this here -> http://rextester.com/ZFHJ5703

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

you have to perform simple date rage

```
select Id,Name from Events where
 GETDATE () >= EndDateWithTime and GETDATE ()   <= StartDateWithTime
```

Comment: @GopinathYalavarthi - what is the issue ...you want that kind output right

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle SQL, I have used table1 as my test table.
column3 is start date and column4 is end date .

```
SELECT         TRUNC(t.column3) 
             , COUNT(*) AS total_events              
 FROM          table1 t
 WHERE  t.column3<=t.column3 AND t.column4>=t.column3
 GROUP BY      TRUNC(t.column3)
 ORDER BY       TRUNC(t.column3)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use both. If you use Linq you will need more code to write. If you use sql the database server will have to work more.
It actually depends on your architecture.
I would prefer sql

best regards

Comment: Neither of those statements are true. Linq can be more terse than SQL and setting up something like EF can be less code than boilerplate ADO.Net. SQL won't make the database work more if the Linq code is translated in SQL and runs on the DB.